# Using Tikz to Sketch an irregular graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use tikz to sketch these graphs but it looks irregular and don't know how to go about it. I can do almost everything with the exception of the irregular graph in red which I would need help with. Any help would be very much appreciated.Thank you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, decorations, shadows}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}  
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}  
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}  
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,compat=1.5,height=9.5cm,
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
xmin=-5,xmax=5,
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
anchor=center
]
%\addplot[smooth,very thick,mark size=1.5pt,color=red,mark=*] plot coordinates 
{(0,0) (1,-1) (4,-2)}; % node[right] {$y=\sqrt{x}$};

\addplot+[-latex', >=latex,color=red,smooth,very 
thick,mark=none,samples=200,unbounded coords=jump] {sqrt(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, show to us, what you do so far. Your code will be easy to complete with missing curve.

Comment: I reformat your MWE and correct spelling error in it. However in it is missing, as can I see, package `pgfplots` (I didn't add it, since your MWE is in contradiction with your question). Now it is not very clear, what is your problem. Your function? If for it you don't know math function, you can determine  it with coordinates and draw smooth curve through points. is this your problem?

Comment: Thanks but I only wanted how I could plot the red graph in the picture using one of my old code for \sqrt{x} graph. Please  help.

Comment: See, if my answer fit to your wishes. Let me note: i don't understand what you mean with *irregular graph*, so I use two ordinary function and draw their graphs in selected domain.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the question is not very clear to me, so this answer is based on guessing and provided desired images. This means, that your MWE wasn't very helpful. From it I only see, that you expect figure drawn by `pgfplots` and not by pure `tikz` ...

See, if my result is what you after:

[image]

Above images is done by the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{width=6cm, compat=1.13,
                 title style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}, anchor=north, font=\large},
                 xlabel style = {anchor=west},
                 ylabel style = {anchor=south},
                 clip=false
                  }% <-- common styles 
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%small,anchor=aninnernode.center,
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
%
xmin=-0.5,xmax=5,
ymin=-0.5,ymax=5,
xtick={0}, ytick={0},% this disables the standard
ylabel=$y$,
xlabel=$x$,
title = {$f$ is increasing},
]
\addplot[line width=2pt,red,%
         domain=0.5:4.5, samples=9, mark=none,
         ->] {0.2*(x^2) + 1};
\node[right] at (4.5,{0.2*(4.5^2) + 1})  {$f(x)$};
%
\draw[dashed]   (0,{0.2*(2^2) + 1}) node[left] {$f(x_1)$}  -|
                (2, 0)              node[below] {$x_1$}
                (0,{0.2*(3^2) + 1}) node[left] {$f(x_2)$}  -|
                (3, 0)              node[below] {$x_2$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%small,anchor=aninnernode.center,
axis y line=center,
axis x line=middle,
%
xmin=-0.5,xmax=5,
ymin=-0.5,ymax=5,
xtick={0}, ytick={0},% this disables the standard
ylabel=$y$,
xlabel=$x$,
title = {$f$ is decreasing},
]
\addplot[line width=2pt,red,%
         domain=0.5:4.5, samples=9, mark=none,
         ->] {7-3*sqrt(x)};
\node[right] at (4.5,{7-3*sqrt(4.5)})  {$f(x)$};
%
\draw[dashed]   (0,{7-3*sqrt(2)})   node[left] {$f(x_1)$}  -|
                (2, 0)              node[below] {$x_1$}
                (0,{7-3*sqrt(3)})   node[left] {$f(x_2)$}  -|
                (3, 0)              node[below] {$x_2$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code is (almost) semi-explanatory, but if you have some question about it, pleas ask.

**Addendum:** 
The code for pure TikZ solution seems to be slightly simpler:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0.5:4.5, samples=17,]
% axes                        
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- node[below=5mm] {$f$ is increasing}
                      + (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- + (0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
% graph
\draw[line width=2pt, draw=red, ->] 
    plot (\x,{0.2*(\x^2) + 1}) node[right] {$f(x)$};
%
\draw[dashed]   (0,{0.2*(2^2) + 1}) node[left]  {$f(x_1)$}  -|
                (2, 0)              node[below] {$x_1$}
                (0,{0.2*(3^2) + 1}) node[left]  {$f(x_2)$}  -|
                (3, 0)              node[below] {$x_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0.5:4.5, samples=17]
% axes
\draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- node[below=5mm] {$f$ id decreasing}
                      + (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- + (0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
% graph
\draw[line width=2pt, draw=red, ->] 
    plot (\x,{7-3*sqrt(\x)}) node[right]  {$f(x)$};
%
\draw[dashed]   (0,{7-3*sqrt(2)})   node[left] {$f(x_1)$}  -|
                (2, 0)              node[below] {$x_1$}
                (0,{7-3*sqrt(3)})   node[left] {$f(x_2)$}  -|
                (3, 0)              node[below] {$x_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result of above MWE is (almost) the same as at the first solution (with use of `pgfplots`)

Comment: actually morning :-) ...please, get me more information about my answer. provide it what you looking for? as i already noted, i have problems to understand what is your problem. For example, do you like to have pure TikZ solution, without use of the `pgfplots`?

Comment: Actually, I would prefer pure tikzpicture to pgfplots but either am satisfied with your code and it looks good. Thank you.

Comment: Now I added "pure TikZ" solution ...